# Array json from php is not output in the corect way

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to make a json output from my db in php with all of users from sql table but i don't know how to do that..i'm new with this.
I want the code to output like this.

```
[
    {
        "name": "Maybell",
        "avatar": "zeldman/128.jpg",
        "data": {
            "company": "Alibaba",
            "title": "Engineer"
        }
    }
]
```

but the my code does the following output and is not ok.

```
{
    "name": "Maybell",
    "avatar": "zeldman\/128.jpg",
    "company": "alibaba"
    "title": "Engineer"

}
```

Here is the Php code:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/json");
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","testest");
//MSG
$query = "SELECT * FROM mls_users LIMIT 20";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
//Add all records to an array
$rows = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
    $name = $row['name'];
    $avatar = $row['avatar'];
    $company= $row['company'];
    $title= $row['title'];
}
//Return result to jTable
$qryResult = array();
$qryResult['name'] = $name;
$qryResult['avatar'] = $avatar;
$qryResult['company'] = $company;
$qryResult['title'] = $title;

 echo json_encode($qryResult,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
mysqli_close($db);

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/json");
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","testest");
//MSG
$query = "SELECT * FROM mls_users LIMIT 20";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
//Add all records to an array
$users = array();
while($row = $result->mysqli_fetch_assoc()){
    $users[] = [
        'name' => $row['name'],
        'avatar' => $row['avatar'],
        'data' => [
            'company' => $row['company'],
            'title' => $row['title']
        ]
    ]
}

echo json_encode($users,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
mysqli_close($db);

?>
```

I changed fetch_row() to mysqli_fetch_assoc() and then actually made an array with all fetched rows. You kind of wanted to do that i can see that in comments but you didnt. Then just json encode it.

The outlining brackets `[` and `]` should come automatically when the array has multiple elements in it.

Comment: Thank you guys! u're the best :)

Answer (score 4):

Just change:

```
//Add all records to an array
$rows = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
    $name = $row['name'];
    $avatar = $row['avatar'];
    $company= $row['company'];
    $title= $row['title'];
}
//Return result to jTable
$qryResult = array();
$qryResult['name'] = $name;
$qryResult['avatar'] = $avatar;
$qryResult['company'] = $company;
$qryResult['title'] = $title;
```

To:

```
//Add all records to an array
$qryResult = [];
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $qryResult[] = [
        'name'   => $row['name'],
        'avatar' => $row['avatar'],
        'data'   => [
            'company' => $row['company'],
            'title'   => $row['title'],
        ],
    ];
}
```

You can skip setting the intermediate variables and just add onto the `$qryResult` array directly.

Comment: No problem @Alex :). If my answer helped you, don't forget to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Not sure why you're getting downvoted, this is correct.

Comment: Won't this still only output the last row? Because the $qryResult array is being initialized after the loop and only the last state of the variables being added to it.

Comment: take a mix of this answer and mine. i did correct the fetching of all rows but oversaw the data array. *edit:* i edited my answer, so it has the data array too

Comment: @Connum Yes, you're right, I've updated my answer. Thanks for your feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, you just need to wrap it in an array and make data an array.

```
$qryResult = array();
$qryResult['name'] = $name;
$qryResult['avatar'] = $avatar;
// Now make an array to hold data
$data = array();
$data['company'] = $company;
$data['title'] = $title;
// Add data to qryResult
$qryResult['data'] = $data
// Wrap qryResult in array so output will be wrapped in array
$outPutResults = array($qryResult);
echo json_encode($outPutResults,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$qryResult = array();
$qryResult['name'] = $name;
$qryResult['avatar'] = $avatar;
$qryResult['data']['company'] = $company;
$qryResult['data']['title'] = $title;
```

Try that way. You are asking for a multidimensional-array so you need to set it up as one.